# NextJS: Recall the data and it's original form

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js

My question is is there a way to call the value on it's original form?

Example:

My textarea values are:

```
Name: Your Name
Email: youremail@mail.com
Contact No: 123456789

Content: 
Whatever it is
```

What I wanted to do is whenever those words saved in my database I'll be getting the same format. Currently, whenever I retrieve data from my database, they appears as one word. Like this:

```
Name: Your Name Email: youremail@mail.com Contact No: 123456789 Content: Whatever it is
```

Here's my code:

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchAllData() {

            const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/rfc/get-all-rfc-by-id/${localStorage.getItem("1003")}`)
            const infos = await res.json()
            setInfo(infos)
        }
        fetchAllData()
    }, [rfcName])
```

This is my HTML Code:

```
<tbody>
    {
    info ? info.map(infos => (<DisplayRFDDataInfo key={info._id} info={infos}/>))
     : <> </>
    }
</tbody>
```

```
const DisplayRFDDataInfo = ({info}) => {

    function createNewDocumentPage(e) {
    }

    return (
        <>
            <tr>
            <td key={info.subject}>{info.subject}</td>
            <td key={info.content}>{info.content}</td>
            <td className="text-center" key={info._id}><Button type="submit" onClick={createNewDocumentPage} className="btn btn-warning">Manage</Button></td>
            </tr>
        </>
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you save your data in JSON format? What is your database?

Comment: Im using mongodb

Comment: Yes it is saved using JSON.stringify()

Comment: Are you saving the string you get from the `textarea` directly in your database? If so it won't be formatted any other way. If you want the data from the database returned in JSON then you'll need to properly format it as a JSON string when you first store it there.

Comment: Yes, it was. Actually, I was able to format it using .innerHTML however calling it to an object it doesnt allow me. I've also check the console.log and it has the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the data returned is in JSON format. I believe you will get the same format (object) if you parse the response data.

```
JSON.parse(resposneData)
```

Comment: Hello Kouta. Regrettably, I've tried to modify it and used JSON.parse but it's giving me the same value. `• Business process, activities that produce a specific service or product for customers • Business process modeling, activity of representing processes of an enterprise in order to deliver improvements`